# SSRS COALESCE from two different datasets

Tags: reporting-services, coalesce, iif

1. I have an SSRS report with a table using 1 data set.
2. I have another data set where I want to use a field if its populated over the field from dataset one.
3. I have put an expression on the column to say if the column from dataset 2 isblank then use the field from dataset 1 but it doesn't seem to work.

`=iif(isNothing(Fields!Comments.Value, "DataSet2",Fields!Comments.Value, "DataSet1",Fields!Comments.Value, "DataSet2")`

Comment: what exactly you want to perform. In your table do you wish to show columns/values from Dataset 1 and Dataset2 both depending on your conditions?

Comment: Could you possibly just use a join in the query and use a case statement to always populate the comments field with the value you want?  I'll also mention that your expression is poorly formulated.  It should be `=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Comments.Value, "DataSet2"), Fields!Comments.Value, First(Fields!Comments.Value, "DataSet2"))`.  When referencing another dataset with the scope, you'll need to use an aggregate.